# SImplenews module. Where does the form come from?

Tags: emails

I would like to modify the content of the simplenews form, but where is it being generated from?

```
<?php print render($form); ?>
```

I would like to change the "E-mail" wording, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify a form in Drupal you dont need to get where the form is built.

You can make use of [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify the form

> Perform alterations before a form is rendered. One popular use of this
>   hook is to add form elements to the node form.

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id);
```

> Parameters
>
> $form: Nested array of form elements that comprise the form.
>
> $form_state: A keyed array containing the current state of the form.
>   The arguments that drupal_get_form() was originally called with are
>   available in the array $form_state['build_info']['args'].
>
> $form_id: String representing the name of the form itself. Typically
>   this is the name of the function that generated the form.

**What is a Hook ?**

Basically they provide a way for a module to extend the functionality of another module. They would go in a module and 'hook' would be replaced by the actual module name.

**Please try**

[Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples)

[Drupal Hooks Explained](http://mccormickandwinter.com/blog/drupal-hooks-explained)

Comment: Thank you @nikhilM

I've never worked with hooks before. Any tutorials you recommend?

Comment: @kine456, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, I don't need to create a new module, is that right? I just edit the template.php file, is that correct?

Comment: @kine456, read my answer.. `hooks` would go in a module and 'hook' would be replaced by the actual module name. Not in template.php, but there are hooks can be in template.php

Comment: thank you again @nikhilM

My modules are being recognised for some reason :(